# Passing Shibboleth credentials after successful authentication

Tags: single-sign-on, federated-identity, shibboleth

I have a high-level/conceptual question about Shibboleth.

I'm working on the front-end (running Drupal) of a data-driven web app.  End-users interact with the front-end to construct data queries, which makes background requests to a caching/archiving data proxy (the "data retrieval service"), which in turn either delivers data from its cache or goes out and queries still more services ("out there") which have desired data.  So far so good... it is ornate, but only as ornate as the problem we're trying to solve.

Here's the wrinkle: Some of services queried by the data retrieval service want to implement user-level authentication, so that some users may access their data, but others cannot. For organizational reasons, our identity and authentication mechanism is likely to be Shibboleth.

So, here's my scenario: a user logs in to the frontend using Shibboleth. Now, can my frontend, and in turn, the data retrieval service, authenticate against against external services as the user? And if so, how does that work in practice (what authentication data gets passed from server to server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can - you service has to exist in the identity provider (how it is set up is up to you)